# R: returning the minimum positive number

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with positive and negative numbers.
What I need to return is the smallest positive number.
Is there a function that does this?

```
 dfcount  <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4,-5,-6,-7))
```

ie    minpositive(dfcount) returns 1 and not -7

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you including 0 as positive?

Comment: Also: in your case it looks like you want to search an entire data frame. Are all the columns in the data frame numeric? (If so, wouldn't it be easier to convert it to a matrix?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This function would work:

```
minpositive = function(x) min(x[x > 0])
```

For example:

```
dfcount  <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4,-5,-6,-7))
minpositive(dfcount)
# 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
min(dfcount$A[dfcount$A > 0])
```